# Clicking 'OK' in confirmation does not submit page

Tags: jquery, html

I have a simple button in my `<body>` section of code:

```
<p><button id='submitstudents'>Submit Students</button></p>
```

What I want the button to do is that if clicked on, it will go through the `editvalidation()` function to see if there are any errors, if there are no errors then it displays a confirmation box, if the user confirms then it should perform the ajax.

Problem is that when I click on the `OK` button in the confirmation box, nothing happens at all, page doesn't even do any loading, my question is what is causing the page to not submit after clicking on the `OK` button in confirmation?

The is no errors in the error console.

Jquery code (in correct order displayed):

Validation:

```
function editvalidation()
{
    if ($("#sessionsDrop").val()==""){
        $("#studentAlert").html("Please Select an Assessment to edit from the Assessment Drop Down Menu");
    }
    if ($("#sessionsDrop").val()!="" && $("#studentadd").children().length==0){
        $("#studentAlert").html("You have not Selected any Students you wish to Add into Assessment");
    }
    if ($("#sessionsDrop").val()!="" && $("#studentadd").children().length!=0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

submit form:

```
     function submitform() {    

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "updatestudentsession.php",
    data: { 
        sessionid:  $('#currentid').val(),
        students:   $('#addtextarea').val()
    },
            dataType:'json',  //get response as json
            success: function(result){
                        if(result.errorflag){

           //do your stuff on getting error message
          var newHtml="<span style='color: red'>"+result.msg+"</span>"; 
          $("#targetdiv").html(newHtml);  //i am displaying the error msg here

        }else{
           //you got success message

           var newHtml="<span style='color: green'>"+result.msg+"</span>"; 
                $("#targetdiv").html(newHtml);


               //append students you want to add to assessment into student exist select box 
               var selectedStudents = jQuery("select#studentadd").find("option");
                selectedStudents.appendTo($("select#studentexist"));
                $('option.red', 'select#studentexist').remove(); 

                 //blank #studentadd select box
                 $('#studentadd').empty(); 

                    $('#targetdiv').show();
            }
        }
      }); 
}
```

Confirmation:

```
         function showConfirm(){

          var examInput = document.getElementById('currentAssessment').value;

          if (editvalidation()) {

         var confirmMsg=confirm("Are you sure you want to add your selected Students to this Assessment:" + "\n" + "Exam: " + examInput);

         if (confirmMsg==true)
         {
         submitform();   
     }
  }
}
```

Button click:

```
$('body').on('click', '#submitstudents', showConfirm);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('#submitstudents').click(function(){
    showConfirm();
});
```

EDIT:

Your script should work. Put all the `functions` and `handler` for the `click` event inside `$(document).ready(function(){ //Code goes here });`.

Also make sure the `jquery` library is linked.

Comment: No that hasn't changed anything. Must be something else in my code. Is there a certain piece of code you may want to look at whre you think a problem may be when a button doesn't do anything? Do you want me to post my HTML forms in question?

Comment: Fixed it. You are missing a closing `}` in your `submitform()`.

Comment: Sorry dunil, that was a paste error on SO, I do have that closing bracket, sorry about that

Comment: If that's the case your code should be working. I have updated my answer. I tested your scripts and it's working fine.